# Kendo UI Grid drop down/select menu

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui

How would I bring in a select drop down into one of my Kendo ui grid columns using remote data?

The documentation is very limited on this subject, specifically with my requirement which is:

To have a list of options from my PHP/MySQL script populate the drop down menu.

If one of those options is already set based on a query in the database, have that option in the menu already selected.

---

Based on the answer provided I now have the following, but it is not working. I get a dropdown list with a load of options all 'undefined':

```
function categoryDropDownEditor(container, options) {
$('<input required data-text-field="'+options.field+'" data-value-field="'+options.field+'" data-bind="value:' + options.field + '"/>')
    .appendTo(container)
    .kendoDropDownList({
        autoBind: false,
        dataTextField: "text",
        dataValueField: "value",
        dataSource: {
            type: "POST",
            transport: {
                read: ROOT+"user/branch-list"
            }
        },
        index: 0
    });
}
```

My PHP script just returns JSON like so:

```
[{text: "Germany", value: "1"}]
```

Comment: Please, remove `data-text-field` and `data-value-field` from the input definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`editor`](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/grid#columnseditor-function) when define the column for that field.

```
{ field: "color", title: "Color", editor: editColor }
```

where `editColor` is a function defined as:

```
var data = [
     { text: "Black", value: "1" },
     { text: "Orange", value: "2" },
     { text: "Grey", value: "3" }
];

function editColor(container, options) {
    $('<input data-bind="value:' + options.field + '" '"/>')
            .appendTo(container)
            .kendoDropDownList({
                dataTextField: "text",
                dataValueField: "value",
                dataSource: data,
                index: 0,
            });
}
```

You might set in `kendoDropDownList` whichever [configuration option](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/dropdownlist#configuration) you need.

Comment: Thanks, but I am trying to substitute the hard variable 'data' with JSON being returned by my PHP script. Could you tell me where I am going wrong with this? (see edit above)

Comment: I included `data-text-field` and `data-value-field` in the `input` field but since they are defined in `kendoDropDownList` they shouldn't. I edited and fixed the example. Thanks.

Comment: I am still getting a list full of undefined options :(

Comment: One further question, is your php returning `[{text: "Germany", value: "1"}]` or `[{"text": "Germany", "value": "1"}]` (the difference are the quotes around `text` and `value`. The former is invalid if you are returning it from a service (it's valid only as JSON definition in JavaScript code).

Comment: The later now I have changed it, but still undefined options :/

Comment: @imperium2335, the following JSFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/JvJDk/3/) is what I've used for testing. At the very beginning of the JavaScript you will find a PHP that is what is in the server. I've tested this and it works. Try using my PHP with your HTML and viceversa.

Answer (score 0):

Also you may want to check that your datasource is parsing your data correctly.

For example my json looks like this you can see that the actual records are are contained within the _*ENTITIES array.  So in order for the the datasource to parse this correctly I have to specify data : "*_ENTITIES" in the schema for my datasource.  I hope this helps

schema : {
            model : myModel,
            data : "__ENTITIES"
        }

{"_*entityModel":"Contact","*_COUNT":13,"_*SENT":13,"*_FIRST":0,"_*ENTITIES":[{"*_KEY":"177","_*STAMP":16,"ID":177,"firstName":"","middleName":"","lastName":"","ContactType":{"*_KEY":"2","_*STAMP":4,"ID":2,"name":"Home","contactCollection":{"*_deferred":{"uri":"/rest/ContactType(2)/contactCollection?$expand=contactCollection"}}},"addressCollection":{"__deferred":{"uri":"/rest/Contact(177)/addressCollection?$expand=addressCollection"}}},

{"_*KEY":"180","*_STAMP":5,"ID":180,"firstName":"a","middleName":"b","lastName":"c","ContactType":{"_*KEY":"2","*_STAMP":4,"ID":2,"name":"Home","contactCollection":{"_*deferred":{"uri":"/rest/ContactType(2)/contactCollection?$expand=contactCollection"}}},"addressCollection":{"*_deferred":{"uri":"/rest/Contact(180)/addressCollection?$expand=addressCollection"}}}